# Usage of Comma to remove ambiguity

Tags: grammar, american-english, punctuation, british-english, north-american-english

> Soon after the military operations, an 11 member committee headed by Mr. ABC was set up to suggest measures that would enhance the combat capability of the armed forces and to also, balance defence expenditure.

In the above news article, they have put the second comma after the word "also". I think it could have been put after the word "forces". What difference would it make?

Comment: Hello, Dhruv. Most Anglophones would consider the (second) comma placement in your example incorrect; it's most probably a typo. Your suggestion works, though some may prefer that comma just to be omitted.

Comment: Either there should be no comma there or there should be another comma before *also*.

Comment: There is a school of though that commas should be placed where you would take a breath when speaking. No doubt there are numerous old posts on the use of commas.

Comment: @Brad I've noticed that I need to take more breaths than I did 50 years ago. But I've got to strive to keep the 'clarity in print trumps marking for articulatability' rule. When clarity's no issue, I'll certainly defend one's right to use the _comma = (fairly short) pause_ convention.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth ,Wait, till your, in, your, sixties, I was only, making , the comment, not defending, the ,rule,

Comment: @Brad (a) You're assuming my age at the earlier time I referenced. (b) Is 'as clear as mud' a dissimile? [Will someone kindly italicise the _dis_?]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need "and" as well as "also". The sentence would be better expressed as "...to suggest measures that would enhance the combat capability of the armed forces and to balance defence expenditure." This elimates the need for the comma.